# Creating a char array in C using variables like in a printf

Tags: c, arrays, char

I'm trying to create a char array in a similar way as using a `printf` statement.

If I do this:

```
printf("%d:%d:%.2f", hours, minutes, time);
```

It will print out exactly how I want it. However I'm now trying to store this as a variable. I've been trying to do something like the line of code below, however I get a "invalid initializer" error for char.

What I'm trying to do:

```
char temp[] = ("%d:%d:%.2f", hours, minutes, time);
```

I've also messed with `strncat` and couldn't figure that out either. Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: You are looking for `sprintf`

Comment: I just don't understand C++ tag. This seems to be C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`sprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) or [`snprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

```
int sprintf( char *restrict buffer, const char *restrict format, ... );

int snprintf( char *restrict buffer, int buf_size,const char *restrict format, ... );
```

---

```
   char temp[30];
   sprintf(temp,"%d:%d:%.2f", hours, minutes, time);
   printf("%s\n",temp);
```

For secure purpose use `snprintf()` as below

```
   char temp[30];
   snprintf(temp,sizeof temp,"%d:%d:%.2f", hours, minutes, time);
   printf("%s\n",temp);
```

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that you should generally _never_ use `sprintf` (especially if any of the arguments are user-supplied or derived from data that's user-supplied). Using `sprintf`, if your formatted data ends up being larger than the buffer you passed it, the result will overflow into space outside the buffer, corrupting data and potentially causing crashes or (worse) a security vulnerability.

`snprintf` avoids this by allowing you to specify the size of the buffer you passed it--  `snprintf` will never overflow its buffer.  Best to get into good security practices early.

Comment: @JonathonW `never use sprintf (especially if any of the arguments are user-supplied or derived from data that's user-supplied)` Indeed info.Thanks for adding.

Comment: Please leave comment when down voted my answer.some users are misusing down vote.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want [`sprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/sprintf), it is the same as `printf`, but instead outputs to a string, as you wish.

**EDIT**: [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/snprintf) is indeed safer. (Thanks Troy)

Comment: `snprintf` would be a safer bet.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`snprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf):

```
char temp[20];
snprintf(temp, sizeof(temp), "%d:%d:%.2f", hours, minutes, time);
```

Comment: `20` => `sizeof temp`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/snprintf) to do that. It is exacly what you need:

```
#include <cstdio>

char temp[50];
snprintf( temp, sizeof(temp), "%d:%d:%.2f", hours, minutes, time);
```

Comment: `50` => `sizeof temp`