# How do I include a variable in a String?

Tags: rust

I think this should be simple, but my Google-fu is weak.  I'm trying to build a String in Rust using a u32 variable.  In C, I would use snprintf, like this:

[Creating a char array in C using variables like in a printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202795/creating-a-char-array-in-c-using-variables-like-in-a-printf)

but I can't find anything on how to do it in Rust.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21324657/1522342

Answer (score 21):

In Rust, the go-to is [string formatting](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html).

```rs
fn main() {
    let num = 1234;
    let str = format!("Number here: {num}");
    println!("str is \"{str}\"");

    // Some types only support printing with debug formatting with :?
    let vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
    println!("vec is {vec:?}");

    // Note that you can only inline variables.
    // Values and expressions cannot be inlined:
    println!("{} + {} = {}", 1, 2, 1 + 2);
}
```

Alternatively (applicable to older versions of Rust), you can write the variables after the string:

```rs
fn main() {
    let num = 1234;
    let str = format!("Number here: {}", num);
    println!("str is \"{}\"", str); 
}
```

While functionally equivalent, the default linter [Clippy](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy) will [suggest writing the first version](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#/uninlined_format_args) when run in `pedantic` mode.

This doesn't always work, particularly if the variable doesn't support the default formatter. There are more details on string formatting [in the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html), including more display settings and how to implement formatting for a custom struct.

---

In most languages, the term for the concept is one of "string formatting" (such as in Rust, Python, or Java) or "string interpolation" (such as in JavaScript or C#).

Comment: Thank you!  I knew it had to be simple, but couldn't find it :D

Comment: @jrbobdobbs83 in general, in most languages, the term is one of "string formatting" or "string interpolation."

Comment: As you learn more, you'll find ways to readily be able to interpolate your own data types into strings. Very useful.

Answer (score 14):

As of Rust 1.58, you can also write `format!("Hey {num}")`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70504075) for more.

Answer (score 5):

### How to write formatted text to String

Just use [format!](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#usage) macro.

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = format!("test");
    assert_eq!(a, "test");
    
    let b = format!("hello {}", "world!");
    assert_eq!(b, "hello world!");
    
    let c = format!("x = {}, y = {y}", 10, y = 30);
    assert_eq!(c, "x = 10, y = 30");
}
```

### How to convert a single value to a string

Just use [.to_string()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html) method.

```rust
fn main() {
    let i = 5;
    let five = String::from("5");
    assert_eq!(five, i.to_string());
}
```